# Scrape Multiple Websites and Send Text Message if Conditions are met

Tags: python, listener

I have two different snippets of code that scrape from two different websites. Code is a modified version from an answer from a user on SO. I would like to consolidate it to run both URLs in one code so I do not have to have two command prompts open. Not trying to create a retail bot, just status checks. I am not proficient at Python, so my question is how do I complete this code to have this workflow?

1. Scrape two different URLs at a set interval and have it running around the clock without terminating.
2. Check if the stock status has changed from out of stock to in stock and if conditions are met....
3. Sends a text message (not email) to me confirming it is in stock.

   ```
   import re
   import time
   import smtplib
   import requests
   from datetime import datetime 
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   def stock_check(url):
       """Checks url for 'Out of stock' substring in stock out-of- stock"""
       soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser") #Need to use lxml parser
       stock = soup.find("p", "stock out-of-stock") #Check the html tags for sold out/coming soon info.
       stock_status = re.findall(r"Out of stock", str(stock)) #Returns list of captured substring if exists.    
       return stock_status # returns "sold out!" from soup string.

   def send_email(address, password, message):
       """Send an e-mail to yourself!"""
       server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) #e-mail server
       server.ehlo()
       server.starttls()
       server.login(address,password) #login
       message = str('K8-B is in stock at Kulp Lights') #message to email yourself
       server.sendmail(address,address,message) #send the email through dedicated server
       return

   def stock_check_listener(url, address, password, run_hours):
       """Periodically checks stock information."""
       listen = True # listen boolean
       start = datetime.now() # start time
       while(listen): #while listen = True, run loop
           if "Out of stock" in stock_check(url): #check page
               now = datetime.now()
               print(str(now) + ": Not in stock at Kulp Lights.")
           else:
               now = datetime.now()
               message = str(now) + ": NOW IN STOCK at Kulp Lights!"
               print(message)
               send_email(address, password, message)
               listen = False

           duration = (now - start)
           seconds = duration.total_seconds()
           hours = int(seconds/3600)
           if hours >= run_hours: #check run time
               print("Finished.")
               listen = False

           time.sleep(60*60) #Wait N minutes to check again.    
       return

       if __name__=="__main__":

       #Set url and userAgent header for javascript issues.
       page = "https://kulplights.com/product/k8-b/"

       headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
   'Content-Type': 'text/html'}    

       #URL request.
       url = requests.get(url=page,
                      headers=headers)    

       #Run listener to stream stock checks.
       address = "me@address.com" #your email
       password = "mypassword" #your email password
       stock_check_listener(url=url,
                            address=address,
                            password=password,
                            run_hours=24)
   ```

Comment: Not sure what is your concret question in this context - Improving your question with some more details and expected result would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code here

Comment: to send a SMS you need to sign up and pay an SMS provider with an API that you can register for and use in code. There are many.

Answer (score 0):

> Scrape two different URLs

Unless both urls have the same html structure, you'd want to write a function for each

> at a set interval and have it running around the clock without terminating.

Use  your OS for this; `cron` or Windows Scheduler, not a sleeping loop from Python. You can use a loop for capturing temporary errors like page timeouts, but otherwise you will want the script to terminate on each scheduled interval. Otherwise, your computer will accumulate a backlog of processes and eventually run out of memory.

> run both URLs in one code

After you implement two functions, then call them both. Or call your current one with different urls

> Check if the stock status has changed from out of stock to in stock

You'll need to know what html structure each site has when this things are in/out of stock

I'd suggest returning true/false, or a number of items in stock (if the amount is available), rather than only a string.

> Sends a text message (not email)

You'll need a different library than smtp, then. There's no builtin module in python for sending sms. Telegram, Slack, or Discord might be better alternative if you don't want to pay for an SMS provider

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The other site's code is as follows: `def stock_check(url):
    """Checks url for 'Out of stock' substring in pt-1 mb-2"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser") #Need to use lxml parser
    stock = soup.find('div', class_='pt-1 mb-2') #Check the html tags for sold out/coming soon info.
    stock_status = re.findall(r"Out of Stock", str(stock)) #Returns list of captured substring if exists.   
    return stock_status # returns "sold out!" from soup string.` I am just wanting to use a simple If not True then False function

Comment: I suggest editing your question, but seeing the other sites code doesn't change my answer